# How to pass data in combo box in one form to the gridview in another form in windows application using C#.net

Tags: c#

I have a gridview in one form and a combo box in another form.If i select a value in the combo box that value should be passed to the gridview.how can i achieve this...

Comment: Please clarify what technology are you dealing with - WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc ...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your question has too few details, but as a suggestion I'll try to put some code and maybe it'll give you some hint.

```
// In case if you're dealing with WinForms
// For WPF solution could have similar approach

public class DataGridForm : Form
{
    private DataGrid _grid;

    public DataGridForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();// <-- here _grid is instantiated      
    }

    public void LoadData(object data)
    {
        // load data into grid
        // I don't know, could be smt like
        DataGridCell cell = _grid.Cells[0,0];
        cell.Value = data; 
    }
}

public class FormWithComboBox : Form
{
    private ComboBox _comboBox;

    public DataGridForm DataGridForm { get; set; }// value is set by some externat user

    public FormWithComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();// <-- here _grid is instantiated      
        // including handler for OnSelectedItemChanged event
    }

    private void _comboBox_OnSelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridForm.LoadData(_comboBox.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```